# How to detach a node from its parent and attach to another in SpriteKit

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I am trying to quickly detach a node from its parent and attach to another node, in order to accurately follow the position of the parent. I use the following code:

```
    // detach from parent
    [_player removeFromParent];

    // attach back to world node, at the same visual location, before taking action
    [_player setCenterPosition: CGPointMake(newPosX,newPosY)];   
    [_worldNode addChild:_player];
```

However, I have flickering at the second running this code, and it does not look flawless. Is there a faster way to attach/detach node from its parent?

Comment: Don't know why you are doing this but there's definitely a solution that works without "reparenting", and arguably it'll be a better solution too. At its most basic level it just requires setting the position in scene's update: to another node's position.

Comment: Is it possible that there is an `SKAction` in progress still for the node ?

Comment: Is there any other code that affects the position of that node ? And that it might still change it's location, even if just for a frame ? What you are doing should work, however my guess is that there is something else causing the issue, that you don't assume should be a factor. I'm also assuming that whatever is in `setCenterPosition` does exactly what you expect.

Comment: I just did a test with removing a parent and adding it to another, and it works just fine so long as I calculate the new location correctly. I get no flicker. So as I was thinking there is more at play here.

Comment: The reason I am tracking another node (who has SKAction movement), is that the player sits on this node. When I want the player to jump/move I have to detach the player node. If I just update the position of the player according to the moving node, I have a small delay that causes a drift which looks bad.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot transfer a child from one parent to another. The only option you have is to remove the node from parent and add to another parent which, as you already figured out, creates an on/off effect.

Not much you can do about a flicker  except change your game logic as to prevent having to switch parents for your node.

Comment: He is removing and adding in the example above. I am able to do this and I don't get a flicker or on/off effect.

Comment: @prototypical - it probably depends on the frame rate at the time when the action is taken. His question though was how to switch parents which, IMHO, is not the best coding option.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that you are saying it creates an on/off effect, which is not the case. Yes, a framerate issue based on what else is going on, might cause a flicker. But nothing that wouldn't happen regardless of the method you chose IMHO. Regardless of best/worst coding option, it works without flicker.

Comment: Undoubtedly, I would think that managing this functionality without removing/adding is likely faster. However the magnitude of that, I'm not sure of. The chance that this is what is causing this flicker, is more what I was speaking to.

Comment: If I am not attaching/detaching and only following the node using update function, I get a drift because of the delay in update.

Comment: maybe I can elaborate the question - what better way there is to "attach" one node to another, assuming that using 'joints' won't help in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Just got back to this question, didn't see your reply in comments until now.

Your clarification in the comments, should be added to the question :

***"what better way there is to "attach" one node to another, assuming that using 'joints' won't help in this case?"***

One concept you could use is to subclass and create a iVar or property where you store a reference to the object that you want to attach it to.

An alternative without subclassing would be to store that reference in the `userData` property of the node.

Then during the update each frame, you could use that reference to update the given nodes position to it's desired parent node.

Here's an example using a flea on a dog , storing in `userData`:

```
flea.userData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[flea.userData setObject:dog forKey:@"parent"];
```

Then in your update when dealing with the flea, you'd do this :

```
SKNode *fleaParent = [flea.userdata valueForKey:@"parent"];
flea.position = fleaParent.position;
```

Of course if flea and dog are in a different coordinate space you'd need to address that as well, but this is just the basic concept of storing a reference.